# How to simulate or restore corrupted WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation)

Tags: windows-8.1, wmi

After fixing a crash that was related to a corrupted WMI, I would like to validate my solution. The problem is, that I meanwhile rebuild the corrupted WMI using https://stackoverflow.com/a/6930421/4609258

I have a backup of the old repository as suggested there. Is there any way, to "restore" the broken WMI or to break it again?